# How to hide a certain path line in svg using just css?

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I have the following [code](https://jsfiddle.net/tdgha203/) using d3 js. I need to be able to hide the overlapped BLUE line on top of the 45 y-axis using just CSS. The code is currently generated by a data I am getting from the backend so I just need to make sure any line that's overlapped inside the svg class chart be hidden.

I've used the following css already but still not enough to hide the overlap:

```
svg:not(:root) {
overflow: visible!important;
    }

div#graphContainer_0 {
overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to delete the blue line in the javascript. You can not work with JS? This is the best practice.

Comment: Not sure how to do this in just CSS. You probably need clip-paths. Good expainer [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2015/07/clipped-paths-in-d3js-aka-clippath.html)

Comment: @SmokeyShakers I already have clip-paths before but they aren't working! :( That's why I wanted to do it with just CSS. Kinda frustrating actually.

Comment: @MickaelLherminez Delete? I dont wanna delete the blue line, I just don't want the lines to overlap the chart class.

Comment: Clip-paths can be tricky. If you'd like to post your JS, I could help get it working. I only see html and css on your fiddle.

Comment: Do you have access to the javascript code that is used to call d3? In that case it would be a better idea to trim the data before it's passed to d3 instead of applying some kind of CSS hack afterwards.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant "hide" (it is an abuse of language). You can keep the values ​​in a variable. And use them according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can see clearly that **Overflow line** use 5 value in **d** attribute of 
path tag.While,other **lines** have 4 values of **d** attribute in path tag.

```
Overflow line

 <path class="line" d="
 M886.9440000000001,
 377.8723404255319L295.648,
 245.10638297872342L0,
 222.6382978723404L-295.648,
 61.27659574468083
 "style="stroke: rgb(0, 173, 242);"></path>

Other lines

 <path class="line" 
 d="M0,
 234.8936170212766L295.648,
 255.31914893617022L886.9440000000001,
 275.74468085106383
 "style="stroke: rgb(186, 187, 193);"></path>
```

Use same values and it will work.

```
 <path class="line" d="
 M886.9440000000001,
 377.8723404255319L295.648,
 245.10638297872342L0,
 222.6382978723404L-295.648
 "style="stroke: rgb(0, 173, 242);"></path>
```

Sorry for first answer.